# Numpy Ceil and Floor "out" Argument

Tags: python, numpy

From the NumPy [docs for ceil](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html#numpy.ceil)  , the `numpy.ceil` function takes two arguments, the second being `out`.  The docs don't say what this `out` parameter does but I assume you can set the output type this function returns, but I cannot get it to work:

```
In [107]: np.ceil(5.5, 'int')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-c05bcf9f1522> in <module>()
----> 1 np.ceil(5.5, 'int')

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

In [108]: np.ceil(5.5, 'int64')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-0937d09b0433> in <module>()
----> 1 np.ceil(5.5, 'int64')

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

Is it possible to use this argument to make `np.ceil` return an integer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`out` is the output *array* (which must have the same shape as the input).

If you construct it to be of the desired `dtype`, that'll be the `dtype` you get:

```
>>> arr = np.array([5.5, -7.2])
>>> out = np.empty_like(arr, dtype=np.int64)
>>> np.ceil(arr, out)
array([ 6, -7], dtype=int64)
>>> out
array([ 6, -7], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 11):

`np.ceil` is one of the `ufuncs`.  The general documentation for this category is:

```
op(X, out=None)
Apply op to X elementwise

Parameters
----------
X : array_like
    Input array.
out : array_like
    An array to store the output. Must be the same shape as `X`.

Returns
-------
r : array_like
    `r` will have the same shape as `X`; if out is provided, `r`
    will be equal to out.
```

`out` and `r` are different ways of getting the function output.  The simplest is to just let the function return the value.  But sometimes you may want give it the array `out` which it will fill.  Controlling the `dtype` is one reason to use `out`.  Another is to conserve memory by 'reusing' an array that already exists.

The array returned by `np.ceil` can also be cast to your desired type, e.g. `np.ceil(x).astype('int')`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify return type.
Try This

```
np.int64(np.ceil(5.5))
np.int(np.ceil(5.5))
np.int(np.ceil(-7.2))
```

Comment: this results in `5.0` while OP's ceil will return `6.0`

Comment: This results in `6`, `6`and `-7` respectively.