# Utility of parameter 'out' in numpy functions

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, parameters

What is the utility of the `out` parameter in certain `numpy` functions such as `cumsum` or `cumprod` or other mathematical functions?

If the result is huge in size does it help to use the `out` parameter to improve computational time or memory efficiency?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041570/numpy-ceil-and-floor-out-argument) gives some information about *how* to use it. But I want to know *when* should I use it and what could the benefits be?

Comment: Did you *read* the answers? E.g. *"Controlling the `dtype` is one reason to use `out`. Another is to conserve memory by 'reusing' an array that already exists."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe
yes I did my dear. But I was looking for a bit more explanation.

Comment: Then *mention that* in your question. What did you understand from that, and what was unclear about it? Try to *be specific* when asking questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you make your comment an answer. The dtype issue is what I came to this post looking for and it isn't addressed in the other answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Functions that take the `out` parameter create new objects. This is usually what you would expect from the function: Give some array and get a new one with the transformed data.

However, imagine you want to call this function several thousand times in a row. Each function call will create a new array, which of course takes a lot of time.

In this case you may want to create an output array `out` and let the function fill the array with the output. After processing the data you can reuse `out` and let the function overwrite its values. This way you won't allocate or free any memory, which can save you a lot of time.

Comment: `array.cumsum(0,out=array)  
array.cumsum(1,out=array)  
array.cumsum(2,out=array)  
`  
is better than  
`array.cumsum(0).cumsum(1).cumsum(2)`

Comment: I think you should still be able to do `array.cumsum(0, out=array).cumsum(1, out=array).cumsum(2, out=array)` if you want to keep it a one-liner.