# never allocate an output of numpy.ufunc

Tags: python, numpy

This question has info on using an input as an output to compute something in place with a `numpy.ufunc`:

- [Numpy passing input array as `out` argument to ufunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398096/numpy-passing-input-array-as-out-argument-to-ufunc)

Is it possible to avoid allocating space for an unwanted output of a `numpy.ufunc`?  For example, say I only want one of the two outputs from `modf`.  Can I ensure that the other, unwanted array is never allocated at all?

I thought passing `_` to `out` might do it, but it throws an error:

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.arange(6)/3
np.modf(ar, out=(ar, _))    

TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

As it says in the docs, passing `None` means that the output array is allocated in the function and returned.  I can ignore the returned values, but it still has to be allocated and populated inside the function.

Comment: Why worry about this?  There aren't many `ufunc` that return more than one array.  How about using `np.remainder(arr, 1)` instead?

Comment: This was more of a question about the limits of `ufunc` than a particular use case.  My additional reading is making me pretty sure it cannot be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can minimize allocation by passing a "fake" array:

```
ar = np.arange(6) / 3
np.modf(ar, ar, np.broadcast_arrays(ar.dtype.type(0), ar)[0])
```

This dummy array is as big as a single `double`, and `modf` will not do allocation internally.

**EDIT** According to suggestions from @Eric and @hpaulj, a more general and long-term solution would be

```
np.lib.stride_tricks._broadcast_to(np.empty(1, ar.dtype), ar.shape, False, False)
```

Comment: `np.broadcast_to(np.empty((), dtype), shape)` is a more general pattern, which works on non-numeric arrays too.

Comment: `np.modf(ar, out=(ar, np.broadcast_to(np.empty((), ar.dtype), ar.shape)))` does not work because the second output is read only

Comment: This is neat! The second output is still an array of the right length, but all elements point to the same location in memory.

Comment: Both `broadcast_to` and `broadcast_arrays` use `np.lib.stride_tricks._broadcast_to`.  One uses a `readonly=True` parameter, the other sets it to `False`.  But there's a TODO comment in the code about changing it to `readonly`, so in the long term this answer may need modification.  It's interesting that the underlying tool in all of this is `nditer`.